# localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString for iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, nsrange

How can i use **localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString** for **iOS 7**?

Because **ragneOfString** method does not give me expected result. But localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString method gives me desired result.

And localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString is not avialable in iOS7.
I tried this but it does't give me desired result

```
 if([session.sessiontitle rangeOfString:searchtext options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location!=NSNotFound 
               || [session.roomname rangeOfString:searchtext options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location!=NSNotFound
               || [session.speakername rangeOfString:searchtext options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location!=NSNotFound
               || [session.speakerprofile rangeOfString:searchtext options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location!=NSNotFound)
            {
                [sessionArray addObject:session];
            }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the localized method.

```
[session.sessiontitle rangeOfString:searchtext options: NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, session.sessiontitle.length) locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]].location!=NSNotFound
```

UPDATE:
This works:
     `NSArray *allNames=@[@"does jenny work",@"JENNy works",@"works with JEnny",@"jack",@"ram",@"jhon"];
    NSMutableArray *results=[NSMutableArray new]; 
    for (NSString *name in allNames) {
        if ([name rangeOfString:@"jenny" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, name.length) locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]].location!=NSNotFound) {
            [results addObject:name];
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"results :>%@<",results);

results :>(
    "does jenny work",
    "JENNy works",
    "works with JEnny"
)<`

Comment: thanks for ur answer but. It doest not sowing result as localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString.

Comment: supoose i am searching for "jenny". But it also showing result which doesn't contain "jenny"

Comment: can you give some examples of false positives? What else returns true?

Comment: let i have array of string--> "jenny","jack","ram","jhon".... it should return jenny only